# OBIEE 11g - Copy MDS and BIPLATFORM schemas for new OBI install

Tags: sql-server, obiee

I had OBIEE 11.1.1.6.4 installed on a windows 7 server.  The app installation was corrupted and I had to re-install.  Well, I re-installed OBIEE 11.1.1.6.12 (only install files I have).  I want to use the same MDS and BIPLATFORM repositories as before, however; I do not have the schema passwords for the MDS and BIPLATFORM schemas.  To get around this, I copied the database and gave new passwords.

When I attempt to hook the OBIEE 11.1.1.6.12 installation up to the copied database, OBIEE config says the BIPLATFORM and MDS schemas cannot be found.  Does anyone know if this can be a version issue?  The copied database was from a 11.1.1.6.4 install and the app is now 11.1.1.6.12.  Is this the problem?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and wanted to post it for others.  There is a table in the repository called dbo.schema_version_registry$.  If you change the schema prefix in the copied database (required if using the same DB), then you will need to manually edit this table to reflect the new prefix!

Took me days to track down but it's just a simple update against the table.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: On Oracle (I'm guessing you've using SQL Server), there is also a system view that you may need SYSTEM.SCHEMA_VERSION_REGISTRY. Without this I can image uninstall/reinstalls might fail.